# azp Claim Missing from Azure AD JWT

Tags: azure-active-directory, jwt

I have registered an app with Azure AD and can get JWT's but I am receiving claims associated to V1 JWT's according to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens) whilst I am expecting claims associated to V2 JWT's.

More specifically, I would like to add the azp claim which is only available under V2.

I've followed [these instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-optional-claims) to add azp but it is not available to add as an optional claim. I am under the impression that I'm using a version 2 app since the endpoints end with /V2 and I also have the ability to add the ipaddr which is only available for V2 apps as far as I understand.

Can anyone point me to what I am missing?

Comment: Did you get a V2.0 token?

Comment: You need to parse the token to see the version of the token.

Comment: thanks for your very detailed answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version of the access token has nothing to do with the endpoint you use to request the token, but is related to the resource you requested. The default version of ms graph api is the token of version `1.0`. If you want to obtain the `2.0` version of the token, you should request your custom api.

First, you need to create an application that represents the api, and then expose the api protected by Azure.

[image]

Next,under 'API permissions', give your front-end application access to your backend api:

- Under 'API permissions' click on 'Add permission', then click on the
  'My APIs' tab.
- Find your backend application and select the appropriate scope.
- Click 'Add permissions'.
- Grant admin consent for your APIs.

[image]

Next, go to the manifest of the front-end application and set the `accessTokenAcceptedVersion` [attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-app-manifest#accesstokenacceptedversion-attribute) to: `2`.

[image]

Next, you need to use the [auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) to obtain an access token,which requires you to log in to the user and obtain the authorization code, and then use the authorization code to redeem the access token.

[image]

Parse the token, it will display `azp` claim and v2.0 version.

[image]